# How to receive value in PostBack page, in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I have made a page which has a checklist having checkboxes with values. I have a button which should send values to a PostBackUrl page, which is not code behind file, but a postback page, called TestPage.aspx.

Now if i have any text field or list box or checklist group, I want to access its values on that page, which is redirected using PostBackUrl.

In code behind, if i do something like FirstName.Text, i receive its value. Can i get something like that on PostBackedPage?

Thanks

Comment: Tell me whether i got it right or not . You have page, say page1.aspx, in which you have checklist having checkboxes with values and a button. You want when button clicks happens, then a new page , say page2.aspx will be loaded which has any text field or list box or checklist group, and now you want these values back in page1.aspx ?

Comment: page1.aspx---->postbackurl---->page2.aspx---->received values from page1 eg firstname lastname etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox myTxt = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("previousPageTextBoxName");
    currentPageTextBox.text = myTxt.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can - you can access named form / post variables from a page using the `Request.Form` collection:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstName = Request.Form["FirstName"];
}
```